# memory and pointers breaking before release

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

The following code, during debugging, always breaks before delete[] p1;. I don't know how to get this to work :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int N = 0;
    double max = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    double *p1 = new double[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cin >> p1[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        if (p1[i] < p1[i + 1]) max = p1[i + 1];
        else max = p1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (p1[i] == max) continue;
        else std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << p1[i] << '\n';
    }**strong text**
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << max << '\n';
    delete[] p1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: another problem is that your `max` search doesn't actually find the maximum, and it's hard to see what the purpose of the third loop is

Answer (score 3):

Just a typo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cin >> p1[N];
```

=>

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cin >> p1[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cin >> p1[N];` is error! Obviously, what you want to do is `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cin >> p1[i];`. By the way, what is your intention? Find the maximum? If so, you code is error, it should be:

```
max = p1[0];
for(int i=1; i<N; ++i)
    if(max < p1[i])
        max = p1[i];
cout << max << endl;
```

You can use the code above to get the maximum. I hope this can help you.